# How to improve mybatis-3's mvn running performance?

Tags: mybatis

I'm trying to run `mvn site` for [mybatis-3](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/), but the build time is take really long time. I even tried to run `mvn site` once, then run `mvn site` again on the same machine. The second time still took almost the same amount of time. It's about 21 mins long.

Is there any way to improve the performance when running mvn?

Comment: Adding `-Dlicense.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true` should speed up the site generation process. It tells Maven to skip tests and license header updates.

Comment: @ave wow, you save me 18mins per run. Thank you! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to speed up the build time, you can simply skip the `license` update process and the `test` phase. That will dramatically reduce the overall build time.

```
mvn site -Dlicense.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Please check [Skipping Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) for further details.

Also, thank @ave for giving the solution in the comment!